# A line of verilog code

Tags: syntax, verilog

I have a line of verilog code which I got online, I do not understand what it means.

```
rom_data <= #`DEL {rom[rom_addr+3],rom[rom_addr+2],rom[rom_addr+1],rom[rom_addr]};
```

Can someone help me debunk this ?

Answer (score 5):

Breaking it down:

```
1 rom_data <=
2 #`DEL 
3 {rom[rom_addr+3], rom[rom_addr+2], rom[rom_addr+1], rom[rom_addr]};
```

1. non-blocking assignment to rom_data, likely used inside `always@(posedge clk)` to imply a flip-flop
2. Delay set by some thing like :

   `define DEL "1ms"

   the 1ms or other value is pasted in where you have `DEL.
3. the `{}` means concatenation, it is taking the rom[rom_addr] and the next 3 values.

   ie {2'b00, 2'b01, 2'b10, 2'b11} => 8'b00_01_10_11

All together you have `rom_addr` pointing at a particular location. When rom_data changes you take the next 4 values, from `rom_addr` to `rom_addr + 3` and assign them to `rom_data` after a delay of `DEL.

Comment: Here is a working example matching @Morgan's explanation at [EDA Playground](http://www.edaplayground.com/s/4/46)